# Name of bifurcation that causes eigenvalues to switch sign in a saddle?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, bifurcation

What is the name for a bifurcation where the signs of the eigenvalues switch?

E.g. Given a 4-dimensional saddle (two positive, two negative real eigenvalues), as I bifurcate a parameter two eigenvalues approach zero and cross zero simultaneously. Therefore at all times during the bifurcation of this parameter there are two positive and two negative eigenvalues, except the instance at which two are zero, one is positive and the other negative.

Is there a name for this behavior?

(I expect the symmetry in the problem, (i.e. the two eigenvalues symmetrically approaching zero together then passing through zero) arises from separation of variables of a single second order ODE into two first order ODEs.)

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is a Hopf bifurcation, if I understood your question correctly. See the following link for more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_bifurcation

Comment: @ErikM If they are passing exactly through zero, this is [Bogdanov-Takens bifurcation](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bogdanov-Takens_bifurcation). For OP: when you want to find a bifurcation, but don't know the right name, first calculate how many conditions you have to impose at critical values of parameters. In your case you impose two conditions to have two zero eigenvalues simulatneously, so you should try to find this bifurcation in [list of codimension two bifurcations, p.293](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~dturaev/kuznetsov.pdf)

Comment: No not a Hopf. Second comment looks promising-- am following up and will add details.

Comment: Not really relevant to your actual question, but this particular type of bifurcation would be hard to detect, because the determinant of the linearization never changes sign in this situation. This sign detection is the default method of bifurcation detection in some software, such as AUTO 07p.

Comment: @Ian Actually, according to AUTO 07p [manual](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/sandsted/auto/auto07p.pdf), they can detect some codimension two bifurcations and Bogdanov-Takens bifurcation in particular.

Comment: @Evgeny I just said it's the default; this is old, fairly general-purpose software, so it doesn't surprise me that it has workarounds.